# How does copy_to_user work on s390?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtual-address-space, address-space, zseries

On the s390 architecture virtual kernel and user address spaces are never present at the same time, so how does `copy_to_user` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`copy_to_user` for s390 is implemented here: [linux/arch/s390/include/asm/uaceess.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.1/arch/s390/include/asm/uaccess.h#L210).

`uaccess` is the pointer to copy_[to/from]_user actual implementation. It is setted up here (grep uaccess): [arch/s390/kernel/setup.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.1/arch/s390/kernel/setup.c). There are 4 implementations of `uaccess`, depening from mode:

`uaccess_mvcos_switch`, `uaccess_pt`, `uaccess_mvcos` and `uaccess_std`

For example uaccess_std is here: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.1/arch/s390/lib/uaccess_std.c

```
4 *  Standard user space access functions based on mvcp/mvcs and doing
5 *  interesting things in the secondary space mode.
```

...

```
82 size_t copy_to_user_std(size_t size, void __user *ptr, const void *x)
83 {
84        unsigned long tmp1, tmp2;
85
86        tmp1 = -256UL;
87        asm volatile(
88                "0: mvcs  0(%0,%1),0(%2),%3\n"
```

The `mvcp`/`mvcs` mechanism is used: 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/topic/com.ibm.zos.r11.ieaa500/iea2a57031.htm

Comment: Also here: www.tachyonsoft.com/s8139db.pdf

Comment: Thank you! So user and kernel address space actually are present at the same time (in the form of home space and primary space resp.)

Comment: Yes. You just can't access kernel space from non-privileged mode.